# Changing integer in a nested list

Tags: python

```
def set(seq, row, col, val):
    if seq[row-1][col-1] != val:
        x = seq.remove(seq[row-1]) #[[32,33]]
        y = seq.pop(row-1) #[50,92]
        z = y.remove(row-1) #[50]  It is wrong from here onwards
        a = y.insert(row-1,val) #[50,50]
        b = x.append(a) # [[32,33],[50,50]]
        return b
```

Given

```
test_case_100 = make_matrix([[32, 33], [50, 92]]) # [[32, 33], [50, 92]]
```

Then the set function should change the matrix as follows

```
set(test_case_100, 2, 2, 50)  # [[32, 33], [50, 50]]
set(test_case_100, 2, 1, 30) #[[32, 33], [30, 50]]
set(test_case_100, 1, 2, 29) #[[32, 29], [30, 50]]
set(test_case_100, 1, 1, -20) #[[-20, 29], [30, 50]]
print(set(test_case_100, 2, 2, 50))  # [[-20, 29], [30, 50]]
```

Comment: Please don't name this `def set`, it shadows the constructor for the built-in `set`. In addition, name your variables something useful! What is `m`, `i`, or `j`? How about `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, or `b`??? Completely meaningless

Comment: Why don't you simply do `m[i-1][j-1] = val`

Comment: @thefourtheye I thought of this before but what do I do after ?

Comment: @user3398505 What? I didn't get your question

Comment: I would still have to remove and insert right?

Comment: so I just return m itself ?

Comment: @user3398505 go try it. You'll find you don't need to return ANYTHING.

Answer (score 2):

As @thefourtheye pointed out in the comments, you're making this MASSIVELY harder than it should be.

```
def set_matrix(matrix, row, col, value):
    try:
        matrix[row-1][col-1] = value
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("No value at x:{}, y:{}".format(row,col))
```

This may be a good time to introduce OOP into your coding style.

```
class Matrix(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self.append(arg)
    def setval(self,row,col,value):
        try:
            self[row-1][col-1] = value
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("No value at x:{}, y:{}".format(row,col))

test_matrix = Matrix([32, 33], [50, 92])
test_matrix.setval(2,2,50)
print(test_matrix) # [[32, 33], [50, 50]]
```

The reason you would use something like a new class here is so you can do cool things like:

```
class Matrix(list):
    # code goes here
    def __str__(self):
        COLSIZE = max(map(len,(val for col in self for val in col)))+1
        NUMCOLS = len(self[0]) # all rows equal size I hope!
        formatstring = "{}{}{}".format("{:>",COLSIZE,"}")*NUMCOLS
        return "\n".join(formatstring.format(*row) for row in self)

>>> print(Matrix([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]))
1 2
3 4
5 6
>>> print(Matrix([226,1],[330,1000],[15,17]))
226 1
330 1000
15  17
```